# What type of model makes sense?

Tags: multiple-regression

I am looking to model physical activity (in minutes) as my dependent variable.  I have several independent variables of the environment around the school (intersections, traffic, etc).

What type of model would make sense?  I was thinking multiple linear regression but some of the variables do not really have a linear relationship.

Comment: Could you tell us something about the evidence you have of nonlinear relationships? In many cases a little bit of nonlinearity won't matter.

Answer (score 6):

Linear regression can accommodate non-straight-line relationships between IVs and the DV through various transformations of variables, addition of polynomial terms and so on.

That is a model like

$y = b_0 + b_1x_1^2 + b_2x_1 + b_3x_3^5$

is a linear model.  But a model such as

$y = b_0 + 2^{b_1x_1}$

is not.

If the data are *really* nonlinear, then the choice of model depends partly on what you know about the relationships. If you don't know much, a spline regression may work well.

Comment: I have tried to create log's for the IV but there is still no linear relationship, is there another way to transform the variables.  Findings to date on the relationships between these variables is quite mixed.  I will look into a spline regression.  Thanks

Comment: Have you looked into Box-Cox? It's been discussed here a lot, and there are also lots of resources on the web.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this suggestion might be too advanced, but if you want to model *duration* (i.e., time until cessation), the appropriate approach is [survival analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis).  Most likely, the [Cox proportional hazards model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_models) is best.

With regard to non-linear relationships, @PeterFlom is giving you good advice that transformations (such as squared terms) and splines can help.

Comment: Is physical activity recorded over time as well as measured in duration of activity?  If so then a time series model might be more appropriate.

Comment: That's a good point, @MichaelChernick, I'm not sure. I'm interpreting "I am looking to model physical activity (in minutes)" as meaning that how many minutes physical activity lasted is the DV, but I could be wrong.

Comment: No I interpret it that way too.  But what is not said is whther or not duration of physical activity is continuously recorded over time or not.  I think your assumption when you suggested survival analysis was that it is recorded once for each of a number of students.

Comment: Yes I am trying to model minutes of PA as the DV.  It is measured as the duration of PA over a 1 hour sample (0 minutes to 60 minutes).  The sample is quite large and evenly distributed.  It is the IV's where they are skewed and have a non-linear relationship.  What is my best bet?  Should I transform the IV's for multiple linear regression?  Or use another form of regression?

Comment: Each student has a number of minutes when they are active (0-60).  No intensity is being included

Comment: I would not divide by 60. Moreover, it PA>60 in some cases, you have censored data, which is the biggest reason for needing SA instead of OLS reg. Note that the dist of your IV's is irrelevant (for more on that, see my answer [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not/33320#33320)). As for non-linear relationships, Peter Flom is giving you good advice.

Comment: No values are over 60 as it was only a 1 hour sample I am looking at.  For the IV's I should run BoxCox?

Comment: So there was no one who was still active when the hour ended? Eg, lets say a child has been resting under a shade tree & then starts playing 10 minutes before the 1 hour sample period ends. When the period ends, that child is still playing. Thus, this child's duration of PA is >10 min, but we don't know by how much; ie that duration is *censored*.

Comment: Yes the child may still be active after the 60 minute sample, but i only want to look at the 1 hour increment.  What they do before or after is irrelevant.  What type of model would you suggest?  Multiple linear or survivor?

Comment: You may only be interested in that hour, but you would be introducing an artifact that will distort your results. You should use SA.

Comment: Ok thanks, so PA will be my time variable, what is my Status variable?  Do I need to adjust the IVs to become linear?

Comment: Your status variable is whether they were still active when the hour ended (be sure you know whether your status encodes *event* or *censored*, software differ on that). I don't know what it means for an IV to be linear; I think of linear as pertaining to a relationship b/t the IV & the DV. If that relationship isn't linear, then you could use squared terms (etc) as Peter Flom suggested.

Comment: Ok so I square the IV's to create a linear relationship with the DV?

Comment: That would be perfectly fine.